# Django ListView loop through info created by a class property (not from the database)

Tags: python-3.x, bootstrap-4, enterprise, django-2.1

On my ListView page, I need to be able to loop through a list of statuses that come from my views.py.

I can do it on the DetailView, but I am struggling with the same process on the ListView.

I have searched and searched and can not seem to find help with my specific problem.

Working code for DetailView:

managers.py

```
class ICCRequestManager:

...

@property
    def statuses(self):
        """ Current status of ICC request """

        if not self.is_submitted:
            yield "Created, not yet submitted"

        if self.is_submitted and not self.legal_signoff_status:
            yield "Waiting for security review"

        if self.is_submitted and not self.security_signoff_status:
            yield "Waiting for legal review"

        if self.legal_signoff_status and self.security_signoff_status:
            yield "Fully reviewed, ICC team is working"
```

views.py

```
from . import managers

...

class ICCRequestMixin:
    """ Mixin for the request model """

    model = models.ICCRequest
    context_object_name = 'icc_request'

class ICCRequestDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, ICCRequestMixin, DetailView):
    """ View to see the current status of an ICC request """

    template_name = "icc/request_status.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """ Add required context """

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["icc_request_manager"] = managers.ICCRequestManager(self.object)

        return context
```

request_status.html

```
    <ul>
        {% for value in icc_request_manager.statuses %}
            <li>{{ value }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

The above displays a simple bulleted list as expected.

Problem code:

views.py

```
class ICCRequestListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ICCRequestMixin, ListView):
    """ View to list requests """

    template_name = "icc/request_list.html"
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """ Add required context """

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["icc_request_manager"] = managers.ICCRequestManager(self.object_list)

        return context
```

Working portion:
request_list.html

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">

    <tr>
        <th scope="col">ICC #</th>
        <th scope="col">Company</th>
        <th scope="col">Brief Description</th>
        <th scope="col">LOB</th>
        <th scope="col">Requester</th>
        <th scope="col">Status</th>
    </tr>

    {% for request in icc_request %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><a href="{% url 'icc:request-detail' pk=request.id %}">{{ request.id }}</a></th>
        <td>{{ request.company_name}}</td>
        <td>{{ request.summary }}</td>
        <td>{{ request.owner_area }}</td>
        <td>{{ request.requested_on_behalf_of }}</td>
        <!--- I want the statuses list here --->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Attempt to loop through like on the detail page:

```
...
<!--- I want the statuses list here --->
<td>
            <ul>
                {% for status in request.icc_request_manager.statuses %}
                <li>
                    {{ status }}
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```

This does not give an error, but it does not display anything (while the request_status.html page does).

Only error is the following linting error on the get_context_data:

> "Parameters differ from overridden 'get_context_data' method."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.

1) `get_context_data` on the ListView has nothing to do with it. Not needed.

2) I needed to change from yields to returning a list:

```
    def statuses(self):
        """ Current status of icc request """

        statuses = list()

        if not self.is_submitted:
            statuses.append("Created, not yet submitted")
        if self.is_submitted and not self.legal_signoff_status:
            statuses.append("Waiting for security sign off")
        if self.is_submitted and not self.security_signoff_status:
            statuses.append("Waiting for security review")
        if self.legal_signoff_status and self.security_signoff_status:
            statuses.append("Fully reviewed, ICC team is working")
        return statuses
```

3) Added a method to the model:

```
    @property
    def get_icc_request_manager(self):
        """ Get the manager for this one request """
        # Needed to import managers inside the method to prevent Circular import problem
        import icc.managers

        mgr = icc.managers.ICCRequestManager(icc_request=self)
        return mgr
```

4) Used `with`:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">

    <tr>
        <th scope="col">ICC #</th>
        <th scope="col">Company</th>
        <th scope="col">Brief Description</th>
        <th scope="col">LOB</th>
        <th scope="col">Requester</th>
        <th scope="col">Status</th>
    </tr>

    {% for request in icc_request %}
        {% with request_manager=request.get_icc_request_manager %}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><a href="{% url 'icc:request-detail' pk=request.id %}">{{ request.id }}</a></th>
            <td>{{ request.company_name}}</td>
            <td>{{ request.summary }}</td>
            <td>{{ request.owner_area }}</td>
            <td>
                {% if request.requested_on_behalf_of %}
                    {{ request.requested_on_behalf_of }}
                {% elif request.requested_by %}
                    {{ request.requested_by }}
                {% else %}
                &nbsp;
                {% endif %}
            </td>

            <td>
                <ul>
                    {% for status in request_manager.statuses %}
                    <li>
                        {{ status }} test 
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </td>
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```